# STM32F4 DISC1 CAN and USB peripheral together doesnt work

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

Hi I  have a problem with stm32f4 disc1.
I can transmit over USB( USB_FS_CDC) message using CDC_Transmit and i can send CAN message but dont get interrupt for receiving CAN message. Interrupt occurs that can message is received only when i dont initialize USB_CDC. 
Hi is it possible to use in the same time can and USB CDC because i need to receive message from can and then transmit over usb to PC?

Comment: Can somebody get some advice ?

Comment: anybody? any advice